# How can I remove whitespace in python?

Tags: python, task, whitespace

[Code,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k4gJ.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cLnP.png)

I want to remove the whitespace at the bracket point and the place before the percentage, how can I do that? Please can I know the simplest way to do it i dont want to over complicate the code

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide code as formatted text *in the question itself*. See [ask].

Comment: can you give example of how you wanna remove white space from string..?

Answer (score 0):

Build a string correctly formatted, then print it instead of using a continuation comma.

```
...
x = temp / 4
strx = str(x) + '%'
print "overall class grades... : " + strx
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I completly forgot the +x+ function only works with strings and not intergers

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`print('\nAfter the lowest mark({}) has been excluded'.format(a[0]))`